# Count ocurrences in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I need to count the occurrences of repeated values ​​in a pyspark dataframe as shown.
In short, when the value is the same, it adds up until the value is different. When the value is different, the count is reset. And I need it to be in a column.

What I have:

```
+------+
| val  |
+------+
| 0    | 
| 0    | 
| 0    |
| 1    |
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 2    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 3    |
| 3    |
| 3    |
+------+
```

What I need:

```
+------+-----+
| val  |ocurr| 
+------+-----+
| 0    | 0   | 
| 0    | 1   | 
| 0    | 2   |
| 1    | 0   |
| 1    | 1   |
| 2    | 0   |
| 2    | 1   |
| 2    | 2   |
| 3    | 0   |
| 3    | 1   |
| 3    | 2   |
| 3    | 3   |
+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `when` and `lag` function to grouping the same concurrent values and use the `row_number` to get the counts. You should have an appropriate ordering column, my temp ordering column `id` is not good because that it is not guaranteed the order-preserving.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0], 'int').toDF('val')

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.orderBy('id')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('id')

df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id()) \
  .withColumn('group', sum(when(col('val') == lag('val', 1, 1).over(w1), 0).otherwise(1)).over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('order', row_number().over(w2) - 1) \
  .orderBy('id').show()

+---+---+-----+-----+
|val| id|group|order|
+---+---+-----+-----+
|  0|  0|    1|    0|
|  0|  1|    1|    1|
|  0|  2|    1|    2|
|  1|  3|    2|    0|
|  1|  4|    2|    1|
|  2|  5|    3|    0|
|  2|  6|    3|    1|
|  2|  7|    3|    2|
|  3|  8|    4|    0|
|  3|  9|    4|    1|
|  3| 10|    4|    2|
|  3| 11|    4|    3|
|  0| 12|    5|    0|
|  0| 13|    5|    1|
|  0| 14|    5|    2|
+---+---+-----+-----+
```